# React Masonry items alignment issue

Tags: reactjs, masonry, react-masonry

I am using react masonry library: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component
I have added three items with different width/height:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvbMg.jpg)

```js
import React from 'react';
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component';

const gridItems = [
    { width:"200px",height: "200px"},
    { width:"100px",height: "100px"},
    { width:"100px",height: "100px"}
].map((i, index) => {

    return <div className={`grid-item`} style={{width: i.width, height: i.height}}>
        <div style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: '100%'}}>{index}</div>
    </div>;
})

const gridView = (props) => {

    return <div className="">
        <Masonry
            className={'masonry-view'}
           >
            {gridItems}
        </Masonry>
    </div>;
}

export default gridView;
```

Issue is visible on attached image - third item is not aligned correctly.
Does anyone know solution?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
Problem was that I had not added columnsWidth property.
So I created Options object and added columnsWidth to smallest column width and it worked.

Comment: also you can write a reusable component to set options once and use those at all

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I just fix the `columnWidth` to 1.

```js
<Masonry
  options={{
     columnWidth: 1,
  }}
>
....
</Masonry>
```